# TypeError: Vector() takes no arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to Implement the set_x, set_y, **init**, and **str** methods in the class Vector above, the output of this test should be:

```
#Vector: x=4, y=4
#Vector: x=5, y=5
#Vector: x=3, y=7
#Vector: x=3, y=7
```

.

```
class Vector:
def __init__(self, x, y):   self.x = x   self.y = y

def set_x(self,x):   set_x = x

def set_y(self,y):   set_y = y

def __str__(self):   return ("Vector: x=%s, y=%s", set_x, set_y)

#__init__ and __str__ v1=Vector(4,4) print(v1)
#Important Remark 
#v1.x,v1.y =4,4 # should return an error since x and y are private

# test set_x and set_y v1.set_x(5) v1.set_y(5) print(v1)

v1.set_x(1) v1.set_y(9) print(v1)

# test __init__ again print(Vector(1,9))
```

Comment: Why would you need a `set_x` method? Just do `v1.x = 1`. If you need additional behaviour, you can use `@property`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def set_x(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def set_y(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Vector: x={self.x}, y={self.y}"

v1 = Vector(1, 9)
print(v1)
```